# Best mechanism for event based communication in C(linux platform)

Tags: linux, multithreading, events, communication

I want to communicate between the two threads. there is only one event that triggers other thread.

My condition would be that event based communication should be efficient. 
i tried using the message queue but usually mq_send takes time.

Comment: my event occurs in once in 1millisecond. i saw mq_send bit costly in my system it takes around 30micro second. in my system i can afford for 20 microsecond for communication over head.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your best way is to use Pthread_mutex and pthread_cond

You should wait for event as follow:

```
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
    pthread_cond_t cond;



    pthread_mutex_lock(&>lock);
    /* releasing the mutex and block untill a cond get a signal*/
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);
    /* execute your code */

    your_condtion = 0;

    /* signaling the producer that we "consumed" the data */
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
```

You shoud send event as follow:

```
    /* checking if consumer already used our data */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    while(your_condition != 0)
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);
    /* execute your code */
            your_condition = 1;
    /* sending event */
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
```

You can use [my producer consumer example](http://www.linux-programmer-guide.com/examples/thread_and_mutex.php) as reference